# Finding max branching in a given tree in Haskell

Tags: haskell, tree

I am a beginner in Haskell. Here I am trying to understand a Haskell function which calculates the max degree of branching in a Tree.

Here is the data type:

```
data Tree a = Node a [Tree a] deriving (Show)

leaf :: a -> Tree a
leaf a = Node a []
```

Here is the implementation:

```
maxBranching :: Tree a -> Int
maxBranching (Node _ ts) = let localBranching = length ts in
                             max localBranching (maxBranchingOfSubtrees ts)

  where maxBranchingOfSubtrees :: [Tree a] -> Int
        maxBranchingOfSubtrees [] = 0
        maxBranchingOfSubtrees (x:xs) = max (maxBranching x) (maxBranchingOfSubtrees xs)
```

And here is the sample input:

```
Node 2 [leaf 7, Node 3 [leaf 0], Node 1 [leaf 3, leaf 2]]
```

I am not understanding this expression:

```
maxBranchingOfSubtrees (x:xs) = max (maxBranching x) (maxBranchingOfSubtrees xs)
```

How *is* `max` comparing the first element with the rest of the list, and where is it updating the max after each iteration? If I see when first element of the list as `Leaf 7` would be passed as `maxBranching x`, there is no such case for that, how it returns the length of the first element of the list and then how is  `maxBranchingOfSubtress` dealing with the rest of the list? Whereas, at first the `localBranching` contains the list `length = 4`? Any kind of detailed help would be appreciated.

Comment: What *is* `leaf`? It's not part of the definition of `Tree`; I assume it's a helper function like `leaf x = Node x []`?

Comment: FWIW, I would spell this function as `maxBranching (Node _ ts) = maximum (length ts:map maxBranching ts)`.

Comment: Yes you assumed right. it is defined as a smart constructor leaf :: a -> Tree a
leaf x = Node x []

Comment: @Sniper Please include problem details in the question section, not the comment section.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer to your question is, all types fit together perfectly.

If `(x:xs) :: [Tree a]`, then `x :: Tree a` and `xs :: [Tree a]`, because `(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]`, or here specifically, `(:) :: Tree a -> [Tree a] -> [Tree a]`:

```
(:) :: Tree a ->       [Tree a]         ->   [Tree a]
(       x         :       xs       )    ::   [Tree a]
----------------------------------
        x :: Tree a       xs :: [Tree a]
```

And from the functions' signatures we have

```
 maxBranching    :: Tree a -> Int
              x  :: Tree a
---------------------------------
(maxBranching x) ::           Int
```

and

```
 maxBranchingOfSubtrees     :: [Tree a] -> Int
                        xs  :: [Tree a]
---------------------------------------------
(maxBranchingOfSubtrees xs) ::             Int
```

so then we indeed can have

```
max :: Int        -> Int                         -> Int
max (maxBranching x) (maxBranchingOfSubtrees xs) :: Int
```

So `max` is *not* "comparing the first element with the rest of the list". Instead, it compares *the result of calculating `maxBranching`* on the first element, with *the result of calculating `maxBranchingOfSubtrees`* on the rest of the list.

And that last bit, how does it know how to do that, you ask? By just using the same `maxBranchingOfSubtrees` recipe. In other words, by *doing the same thing* -- but this time with a "smaller" thing than before. A list's tail is a *part* of the list.

So eventually this *recursion* will run its course and we will have our answer -- if the list of trees is not infinite, that is. So this assumes that the branching factor isn't infinite.

So this finds the maximum branching factor of a node's sub-trees, then compares it with the branching factor of this node, to produce the maximum value overall.

---

Another view of it is that

```
    maxBranchingOfSubtrees [] = 0
    maxBranchingOfSubtrees (x:xs) = max (maxBranching x) (maxBranchingOfSubtrees xs)
                                  = (max . maxBranching) x (maxBranchingOfSubtrees xs)
```

fits the `foldr` pattern,

```
    maxBranchingOfSubtrees = foldr (max . maxBranching) 0
```

and this fits the mapping pattern,

```
    maxBranchingOfSubtrees = foldr max 0 . map maxBranching
```

and there's a built-in function for that,

```
    maxBranchingOfSubtrees = maximum . (0 :) . map maxBranching
```

and so substituting this into the main function we get

```
maxBranching :: Tree a -> Int
maxBranching (Node _ ts) = max (length ts) (maxBranchingOfSubtrees ts)
                         = max (length ts) (maximum (0 : map maxBranching ts))
                         = maximum (length ts : map maxBranching ts)
```

which uses higher order functions to express the same algorithm, instead of the hand-rolled recursion *loop*.